# What's the context of this variable in Mongoose methods?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, this

In the below code, I see the 'this' is used across chaining methods of Mongoose. So, I don't know what the context of the 'this' and what the purpose of using 'this'?

```
PersonSchema
.virtual('name.full')
.get(function () {
  return this.name.first + ' ' + this.name.last;
})
.set(function (setFullNameTo) {
  var split = setFullNameTo.split(' ')
    , firstName = split[0]
    , lastName = split[1];

  this.set('name.first', firstName);
  this.set('name.last', lastName);
});
```

Comment: `this` seems to refer to the current `Person`.

Comment: Or to be more accurate it's the "Model" instance to which the schema is assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

> In model middleware functions, this refers to the model.

---

> In document middleware functions, this refers to the document.

---

> In query middleware functions, this refers to the query.

---

> Aggregate middleware executes when you call exec() on an aggregate object. In aggregate middleware, this refers to the aggregation object.

---

The purpose of the `this` is that you can interact with the data. For example, change a value inside or do other treatment.